# Populate file list with previously uploaded files

Tags: fine-uploader

Using the jQuery wrapped version of Fineuploader v3.3.

Is it possible to populate the file list with files already in the upload folder?

I think "_addToList(id, name)" should do the trick, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a feature planned for the current release cycle.  Please see https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/784 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that they are currently working on this feature:
https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/784

So, this will be available soon.

Comment: The feature is now complete in the develop branch and will be released as part of 4.2 .

Comment: Thanks a lot! When do you plan doing release?

Comment: Probably mid-January.  You can follow the progress of the 4.2 milestone in the github issue tracker.

Comment: Please also have a look at the implementation details in the associated issue in github and add a comment well before the planned release date if you can think of anything we left out of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a behavior that Fine Uploader currently supports. Fine Uploader only displays files that users have submitted to the uploader since the current uploader instance was created.  It doesn't try to be an all-in-one web application.  You could probably add your own item to the list/UI via javascript.  That probably wouldn't be terribly difficult, but seems like an odd thing to do.

If you'd like to discuss your specific use case more, please open up a feature request in the [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues).

Answer (score -2):

Generally, client side code cannot add stored or hard-coded path based file names for use in any type of POST or upload operation.  Obviously this is a security measure, you can imagine if a malicious web page could add to a generic POST operation some type of baked in file name.  So from what I understand, only the user can specify path based file names, via a file browser for the session that it is included in.  This applies to HTML/JavaScript/jQuery but am unsure if Flash/Silverlight based solutions would also be limited.  I think a Java based uploader would be free of this.  But you are just moving closer and closer to installed software.